# How do I make datetime output different times

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, time

Every time someone sends `"!restore"` I need print this date, but every output print the same datetime.

```
import discum
import random
import time
from termcolor import colored
import datetime
import token

now = datetime.datetime.now()
bot = discum.Client(token='token',log={"console":False, "file":False})


@bot.gateway.command
def helloworld(resp):
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto()
        channelID = m['channel_id']
        username = m['author']['username']
        AuthorID = m['author']['id'] 
        if m['content']== '!restore':
            time_to_sleep = random.uniform(2.5, 3.1)
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
            bot.sendMessage(channelID, "$restoreuser " + AuthorID + " 1")
            print(colored(username , 'yellow') , colored("Utilizou Cleanself", 'cyan'), now.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"))
            time_to_sleep2 = random.uniform(3.5, 4.2)
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep2)
            bot.sendMessage(channelID, "**if you haven't been restored, type **__!restore__** again**")
   
bot.gateway.run()
```

`prompt output:`

Lyyne3 Utilizou Cleanself 05-11-22 03:49:04
Lyyne3 Utilizou Cleanself 05-11-22 03:49:04
Lyyne3 Utilizou Cleanself 05-11-22 03:49:04
Lyyne3 Utilizou Cleanself 05-11-22 03:49:04

Comment: put `now = datetime.datetime.now()` inside ur function so the time is calculated each time the function is called. With your current method, it is called during script startup and stored in RAM.

Comment: It worked perfectly, Tyvm;